# How can I add bounty to another person's question if it already has an open bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

A Stack Overflow question has an open bounty and I would like to add a bounty of top of the existing one in order to draw more attention to it since I have the same problem (and want to avoid to open a duplicate).

Is this possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Why would you want to do that at all? The question is already _featured_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ because it's not getting enough attention and I have the same problem (and want to avoid to open a duplicate)

Comment: adding another bounty will not attract more attention, there is only one featured section

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think the logic is that +200 is more of a motivator than +50 for a question to be answered.

Comment: Correct @TheWanderer!

Answer (score 8):

As [Laurel says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380003), this is not possible. Only one bounty can be active at a time on a question, and there is no way to "stack" them.

But it bears pointing out that this isn't just a design oversight or a feature that is waiting to be implemented. There is no good reason to ever have multiple bounties active at a time on a question.

Bounties serve two purposes:

1. To reward an existing answer that is of extremely high quality, or
2. To attract attention to the question in hopes of getting more and better answers.

You are thinking to use a bounty for purpose #2. The way a bounty serves this purpose is that it adds the question to the "featured" tab (which has [apparently now been renamed "Bounties" in the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured). This is, essentially, what you're "paying" for with your reputation—the increased attention that the question will have during the bounty period. Since there's only one "featured" tab, it doesn't make sense to pay twice for exactly the same thing.

You might as well wait until after the current bounty expires, see if it attracted the answer(s) you want. If it did, well, then you got what you wanted for free. If it didn't, *then* offer another bounty of your own.

Comment: True but a greater bounty could attract more people into replying once it's in the Bounties section. This is actually a real scenario for me. A coworker opened a stackoverflow but he put a low bounty. This is an urgent issue for us so i wanted to add more to it.

Comment: And actually that was our plan. We wanted to split the bounty in two so he raised the question and I wanted to add the other half. It would be a nice feature.

Comment: It doesn't really work that way. There isn't anyone out there who knows the answer to your question, but just hasn't provided it because it isn't worth enough reputation points. Bounties work because they attract additional attention.

Comment: Depends on how users use the system, not how it is designed to.. :)

Comment: *"which has apparently now been renamed "Bounties" in the UI"* ? Still appears as *Featured* to me

Comment: @Nick Yeah, it's both.... In the drop-down button, the option is "Bounties". But the name of [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) is still "Featured".

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time.

All you need to do is wait until the other bounty expires or is awarded.